# How to pass an opencv image to display in a Qt scene in a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

I am struggling with memory issues, I think I missed something and would greatly appreciate if someone can point me to what I understand/do wrong.

**What I want to do**

My gui runs in the main thread. I am launching a computation on a separate thread T. The result of this computation is a bunch of opencv images. I want to display them in my gui during the computation.

**How I understand I should do it**

- Launch computation thread.
- When a new image is computed, convert it to a QImage, wrap it in a custom QEvent, and post it to my gui.
- Only use heap memory.

**How I implemented it**

In my computation thread, when a new image is ready :

```
    std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> cvimRGB = std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>(new cv::Mat);
    cv::Mat cvimBGR;
    cv::Mat cvim = MyNewComputedImage;
    cvim.convertTo(cvimBGR,CV_8UC3);
    cv::cvtColor(cvimBGR,*cvimRGB,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    std::shared_ptr<QImage> qim = std::shared_ptr<QImage>(
        new QImage((uint8_t*) cvimRGB->data,cvimRGB->cols,cvimRGB->rows,cvimRGB->step,QImage::Format_RGB888));
    ImageAddedEvent* iae =  new ImageAddedEvent(qim,i);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(gui, iae);
```

In my event handler :

```
bool mosaicage::event(QEvent * e){
    if (e->type() == ImageAdded) {
            ImageAddedEvent* ie = dynamic_cast<ImageAddedEvent*>(e); 
            QImage qim(*(ie->newImage));
            QPixmap pm(QPixmap::fromImage(qim));
            auto p = scene.addPixmap(pm);
            images_on_display.push_back(p);
            return true;
    } else {
            return QWidget::event(e);
    }
}
```

My custom event is defined as follow :

```
    class ImageAddedEvent: public QEvent {
public:
    ImageAddedEvent();
    ~ImageAddedEvent();
    ImageAddedEvent(std::shared_ptr<QImage> im, int i);
    std::shared_ptr<QImage> newImage;
    int index;
};
```

**What happens**

In debug mode, I get crap on display.
In release mode, I get an access violation error.
I am pretty confident about the part where I convert cv::Mat to qimage because I did not change it, I used to update the display from the computation thread but I learned better. It worked though (when it did not crash).

**How I fixed it**

The problem was in the memory pointed by the QImage, which was taken charge of by the cv::Mat I constructed it from. If I want to keep this way of constructing the QImage, using data managed by someone else, I must keep the data valid. Hence I moved the cv::Mat to the custom event :

```
class ImageAddedEvent: public QEvent {
public:
    ImageAddedEvent();
    ~ImageAddedEvent();
    ImageAddedEvent(cv::Mat im, int i);
    QImage newImage;
    cv::Mat cvim;
    int index;
};
```

I changed the constructor of the event to initialize the QImage with the cv::Mat data :

```
ImageAddedEvent::ImageAddedEvent(cv::Mat cvimRGB, int i) : QEvent(ImageAdded),
    index(i),
    cvim(cvimRGB)
{
    newImage = QImage((uint8_t*) cvim.data,cvim.cols,cvim.rows,cvim.step,QImage::Format_RGB888);
}
```

And now I only have to pass a cv::Mat to my event constructor :

```
cv::Mat cvimBGR,cvimRGB;
cv::Mat cvim = MyNewImage;
cvim.convertTo(cvimBGR,CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(cvimBGR,cvimRGB,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
ImageAddedEvent* iae =  new ImageAddedEvent(cvimRGB,i);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(gui, iae);
```

et voilà, again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you use Qt signal/slot mechanism for passing images from thread to GUI? Why do you use shared pointers for storing QImages?

Comment: - The object doing the computation is not a QObject, I think the event mechanism works well for that kind of thing, why would I prefer the signal/slot mechanism ?

- I use shared pointers because I understood I must allocate image on the heap and I don't want to manually deallocate the memory, although I tried with raw pointers that I dealoccate in my custom event destructor, with the exact same result.

Comment: Because you will not need to wrap QImage with a custom event (maintain additional class) and filter events by type. You could pass QImage as a signal argument directly instead. You also do not need to use shared pointers, because QImage implements implicit data sharing itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the wrong constructor

from the [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#QImage-6)(emph mine):

> The buffer **must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage** and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction. You can provide a function pointer cleanupFunction along with an extra pointer cleanupInfo that will be called when the last copy is destroyed.

and you are using the stack allocated `cvimRGB` for the data pointer which (I believe) will clean up the buffer in it's destructor before the event is handled, leading to accessing "crap" data

so you should create a fresh Qimage and then copy the data

```
std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> cvimRGB = std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>(new cv::Mat);
cv::Mat cvimBGR;
cv::Mat cvim = MyNewComputedImage;
cvim.convertTo(cvimBGR,CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(cvimBGR,*cvimRGB,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);

QImage qim =  QImage(cvimRGB->cols,cvimRGB->rows,QImage::Format_RGB888));
//copy from cvimRGB->data to qim.bits()

ImageAddedEvent* iae =  new ImageAddedEvent(qim,i);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(gui, iae);
```

or detach `cvimRGB->data` and let the cleanupFunction delete the buffer

on another note there is no need to use `std::shared_ptr<QImage>` as `QImage` will not copy the underlying data unless needed, This is known in Qt as [implicit data sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/implicit-sharing.html#implicit-data-sharing)

to call the gui you can provide a Q_INVOKABLE method (or just a slot) in `gui` and use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(gui, "imageUpdated", Q_ARG(QImage, qim));`

Comment: Thank you, sir! I fixed the shared buffer thing by moving the cv::Mat that was in charge of the said buffer inside the event. Now it works ans, most importantly, I understand why it didn't!